# Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'LIBCMT.obj'

Tags: c++

I am facing one fatal error in my VC++ project in visual studio 2019,

**Error    LNK1104  cannot open file 'LIBCMT.obj'**

I tried so many suggestions over internet, but its still not gone. Could you please help with some pointers

I have given Linker->Input -> as **LIBCMT** for my VC++ project

Thanks

Comment: what is LIBCMT ?

Comment: If you want a library file as input then you should say so `LIBCMT.lib`. VC++ default input is object files not library files, so you must add `.lib`. But LIBCMT is normally linked by default, so I suspect you have other problems.

Comment: I am using Autodesk FBX files, and building my files with their tutorial , I have added LIBCMT in linker

Comment: Libcmt is long gone from MSVC. It now uses ucrt. Better to create a new solution and not touch the default libraries and paths.